# Question about macro parameter expansion

Tags: siunitx, expansion, programming, units

This question is just for my own understanding of how expansion works.

I'm using the siunitx package in a document. In order to make sure that I'm consistant with myself, I try to write results of measurements as a macro so that I can change them globally from one place.

I noticed that adding a pair of braces `{}` to the end of one of these macros causes an error from siunitx. Have a look at the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\aMeasurement}{0.9(1)}

% This works fine
The answer was \num{\aMeasurement}.

% This gives an error
The answer was \num{\aMeasurement{}}.

\end{document}
```

I thought that parameters to macros were fully expanded before the macro was run. If so, how can `siunitx` possibly tell any difference between these two calls?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your macro, you would get the same error with `\num{123(1){}}`.

Comment: Sometimes the order in which macros expand makes a difference, in which case \expandafter is often used.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Huh, you're right. Do you know why?

Comment: apart from any errors parameters of macros are not expanded unless they are met while expanding the body of the macro. but your example has no parameters (other than `\num`) so the `{}` forms a group

Comment: @CharlieB: I think there is a misunderstanding between "expanding" and "parsing" here. [`siunitx`](//ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) parses the input/argument supplied to `\num`, and doesn't understand what `{...}` represents. The error clearly states "Invalid numerical input".

Comment: I didn't try to find out how \num exactly parses its argument.

Comment: @Werner Actually my error states "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" which I always found annoying about siunitx. You must have a newer version.

Comment: @CharlieB the error message isn't `!!!!!!!!` that is just a separator line before and after the message

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That makes a lot of sense. I've always used SublimeText to compile latex and it looks like it's parsing the error wrong.

Comment: look in the log never trust an editor to show you tex messages (unless it is emacs:-)

Answer (score 6):

Ignoring the specifics of `siunitx` there appear to be some misunderstandings about TeX's execution order.

Firstly macro parameters are not expanded before a macro call they are only expanded (if at all) if the parameter is met after the macro is expanded.

You can see this in

```
\def\foo#1{}


\foo{\somethingundefined}

\bye
```

`\somethingundefined` is not expanded before calling `\foo` (which would have generated an error) in fact as `\foo` does not use `#1` the parameter is never expanded at all.

Secondly `{}` after a macro is not a parameter unless the macro is defined to take a parameter (the macro `\aMeasurement` in your question does not take a parameter)

After

```
\def\foo{hbox}


\foo

\foo{}
```

`\foo` and `\foo{}` are not at all equivalent, `\foo` expands to `hbox` and `\foo{}` expands to `hbox{}` these will take very different code paths for example

```
\csname\foo\endcsname
```

would execute the command `\hbox`  but

```
\csname\foo{}\endcsname
```

would execute the command with name `hbox{}` (which being previously undefined would act like `\relax`)

Comment: Ah, so the problem was that the macro `\aMeasurement{}` didn't exist. I tried redefining `\aMeasurement` to take 1 parameter and indeed it stopped the error from appearing since it now gobbles the `{}`. Thanks!

Comment: @CharlieB no almost certainly that is not the problem in siunitx I just used that example to show the codes were different. You presumably don't want to define your real macro to have an unused parameter as you would then always have to follow it by `{}` which would be rather odd.

Comment: No of course not, that was just a test to see if I was right about the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You may have been misguided by the fact that when a parameterless macro has to be used in text, it should be followed by something that makes LaTeX to respect the space after it:

```
\LaTeX has macros
```

would print no space between the logo and “has”, whereas

```
\LaTeX{} has macros
```

prints correctly. However, this empty pair of braces is *not* swallowed as part of the macro expansion, because TeX knows `\LaTeX` has no argument, so it doesn't look for one.

It would be different if a macro is defined like

```
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{vim}
```

(where the argument is not used) and

```
\vim{} can't be escaped from
```

would indeed swallow the braces. For instance, `\edef\VIM{\foo{}}` would be equivalent to `\def\VIM{vim}`, because the braces disappear as part of argument substitution. On the other hand,

```
\vim\ can't be escaped from
```

would print with *no* space between “vim” and “can't”, because the argument is now “control space” and the macro throws its argument away.

Your input `\num{\aMeasurement{}}` is essentially equivalent to

```
\num{0.9(1){}}
```

and you receive the error message

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! siunitx error: "invalid-token-in-number"
! 
! Invalid token '\q_recursion_tail ' in numerical input.
! 
! See the siunitx documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

The invalid token that's referred to is the open brace `{`. If you scroll past the error, you'll see

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! siunitx error: "invalid-number"
! 
! Invalid numerical input '0.9(1){}'.
! 
! See the siunitx documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

that should be clear enough: \SI`doesn't like at all the tokens`{}`.